# NHibernate mapping problem

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I can't figure out how to get my mappings correct with Nhibernate 3.0

I have have two POCOs:

```
public class Account
{
    public virtual string AccountNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<AccountSummary> AccountSummaries { get; set; }
}

public class AccountSummary
{
    public virtual uint Id { get; protected set; }

    public virtual string AccountNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime TradeDate { get; set; }
}
```

I want to map the classes in tables like this:

Table: accounts (column: account_number)

Table: account_summaries(column: id, column: trade_date, column: account_number)

How can I avoid having a Account object in the AccountSummary class, as I normally would do do with a one-to-many/many-to-one mapping. Instead of my AccountSummary class having a Account object I want the AccountSummary class to have a AccountNumber property as in the class definition with a reference to the Account class.

I would also like to map the trade_date and account_number columns as natural-id or unique-key.

My mappings look like this:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                           assembly="FundAccountDBExperiment"
                           namespace="FundAccountDBExperiment.Models">
  <class name="Account" table="accounts">
    <composite-id>
      <key-property name="AccountNumber" column="account_number" length="40"/>
    </composite-id>
    <bag name="AccountSummaries" table="account_summaries" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true">
      <key column="account_number"/>
      <one-to-many class="AccountSummary"/>
    </bag>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                            assembly="FundAccountDBExperiment"
                            namespace="FundAccountDBExperiment.Models">
  <class name="AccountSummary" table="account_summaries">
    <id name="Id" column="id">
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="TradeDate" column="trade_date" type="date" not-null="true"/>
    <join table="account">
      <key column="acount_number"/>
    </join>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Cant you map acount_number under AccountSummary as a simple property?

Comment: Why do you want to "avoid having a Account object in the AccountSummary class" in the first place?  What is the real problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: If I map Account as an object in the AccountSummary class I would need to refactor code. I prefer to have the AccountSummary class have a AccountNumber string property which mean no refactoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wouldn't this suffice?

```
public class AccountSummary
{
    public virtual uint Id { get; protected set; }

    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }

    public virtual string AccountNumber
    {
        get { return Account.AccountNumber; }
        set { Account.AccountNumber = value; }
    }

    public virtual DateTime TradeDate { get; set; }
}
```

and the unique constraint see "myUniqueIndex"

```
  <class name="AccountSummary" table="account_summaries">
    <id name="Id" column="id">
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="TradeDate" column="trade_date" type="date" not-null="true" index="myUniqueIndex" />
    <many-to-one column="acount_number" lazy="false" index="myUniqueIndex">
  </class>
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Firo. That's what I was looking for. I was trying to set a relationship between parent-child on a property of a class, not the class itself. I'm still not sure if its possible, ie setup the above relation without the Account object in the AccountSummary class. I guess that's why its called and Object Relations Mapper, not a property relations mapper?

Comment: IMO it's not (elegant) possible. But the above should be more flexibility. you can access Account and dont need to refactor, but when you extend account, AccountSummary doesnt have to change